Check if database supports colocation in YugabyteDB?
Can I issue a sql-query to detect if a database supports colocation? I would like to have a check to see if a database or a table has the colocation property set ON or OFF, true/false… I currently have a scirpt creating 3 tables and one of those will normally fail, the result tells me if the database supports coloc (currently, and not sure if it is foolproof even..). Is it possible to “externalize” this property to some SQL-table or view, or is this possibly already the case.

There is a function called yb_table_properties that should help (see is_colocated column below)
yugabyte=# CREATE DATABASE c with COLOCATION = true;
CREATE DATABASE

yugabyte=# \c c
You are now connected to database "c" as user "yugabyte".

c=# CREATE TABLE t (c1 INT);
CREATE TABLE

c=# SELECT * FROM yb_table_properties('t'::regclass);
 num_tablets | num_hash_key_columns | is_colocated | tablegroup_oid | colocation_id
-------------+----------------------+--------------+----------------+---------------
        1 |                 0 | t           |       16392 | 1639512673
(1 row)

There is also a function yb_is_database_colocated that you can run to determine if the database you are connected to is colocated:
c=# SELECT yb_is_database_colocated();
 yb_is_database_colocated
--------------------------
 t
(1 row)

c=# \c yugabyte
You are now connected to database "yugabyte" as user "yugabyte".

yugabyte=# SELECT yb_is_database_colocated();
 yb_is_database_colocated
--------------------------
 f
(1 row)

